# Как составить SQL запрос с объединением и пересчетом значения?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы

Первая:

```
[
 { id: 1, name: Москва },
 { id: 2, name: Минск },
 { id: 3, name: Берлин},
]
```

Вторая:

```
[
 { countyId: 1, value: 45 },
 { countyId: 1, value: 15 },
 { countyId: 2, value: 5 },
 { countyId: 2, value: 5 },
 { countyId: 2, value: 10 },
 { countyId: 3, value: 1 },
]
```

Должны прийти такие данные:

```
[
 { id: 1, name: Москва, value: 60 },
 { id: 2, name: Минск, value: 20 },
 { id: 3, name: Берлин, value: 1},
]
```

Comment: JOIN + GROUP BY + SUM()

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tablename1.id,tablename1.name,SUM(tablename2.value) 
FROM tablename1 INNER JOIN tablename2 ON tablename1.id = tablename2.countyId
GROUP BY tabnlename1.id 
или 
GROUP BY tabnlename1.id, tablename1.name
```